# variables being passed in parameter not found in java

Tags: java, parameters

To start off I'm going to say I have a variable called **size** that I declare in the main method that I pass(or try to anyway) as a parameter to the other methods (which call different class files). Size is a variable that are being fed into the command line arguments like So: c 10 l 5 s 6. I parsed each of these and redirected them using switch.

Long story short my compiler is giving me these errors and I keep trying to fix them but can't figure it out.

```
/home/miguel/School/project 3/driver.java:31: error: '.class' expected
            mySquare( int size );
                          ^
/home/miguel/School/project 3/driver.java:31: error: ';' expected
            mySquare( int size );
                              ^
/home/miguel/School/project 3/driver.java:46: error: '.class' expected
        char2D( int size, int totSize)
                    ^
/home/miguel/School/project 3/driver.java:46: error: ';' expected
        char2D( int size, int totSize)
                        ^
/home/miguel/School/project 3/driver.java:46: error: ';' expected
        char2D( int size, int totSize)
```

And this is the code:

```
public class driver {
    public void main(String[] args){
        String type = args[0];
        int size;

        switch (type.toLowerCase().charAt(0)) {
            case 'l': 
                size = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
                myLine(size);
                break;
            case 's':
                size = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
                mySquare(size);
                break; 
            case 'c': 
                size = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
                myCube(size);
                break;
        }
    }

    public void myLine(int size) {                     // 
        myLine(size);
    }

    // System.out.print("*");                  // don't need to print in here

    //myLine(int size); 
    public int mySquare(int size) {
        //for (i = 0; i < size ; i++)
            mySquare(int size);
    }

    public void myCube(int size) {                                     // z will be x but only have the length of it 
        //z = size + .5
        //  myCube(size)
    }

    public int char2D(int size) {
        char[][] char2D = new char[1][1];   // figure out size of array later and replace 1 with variable totSize
        int x1 = 1;
        this.size = size;

        char2D(int size, int totSize)
    }
}
```

**Additional code in myLine class**

```
public class myLine extends char2D {
    public int myLine(int size) {
        for (i = 0; i < size ; i++)
            System.out.print("*");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In this code:

```
 public int mySquare( int size ) {
    //for (i = 0; i < size ; i++)
    mySquare( int size );
 }
```

the third line `mySquare(int size);` doesn't make sense. If it is supposed to be a function call, the type declaration `int` should not be there. Then the function will recursively call itself until your stack overflows and the program crashes.

You have a similar problem later on with:

```
char2D( int size, int totSize)
```

If it supposed to be a function call, it needs a semicolon after it, and not to have `int` in front of its arguments. But it's still not going to match any function declared in your class, because the `char2D` you declare as a function only takes one argument.

Comment: And if it's a method call, it's wrong, because the method would be calling itself, inevitably leading to a `StackOverflowError`.

Comment: Thanks. If I were to make it call a different class file how should it look like ? I'm basically trying to extend another file called mySquare to here and thought it was correct

Comment: @MiguelPinedo That's too vague. Include all the necessary information in your question and we can try and answer it.

Comment: @khelwood Okay so I'm trying to run this using multiple files that using inheritance. What I'm trying to do is to have this method in my driver file call to my other file called mySquare and pass in the variable size that I parsed in my main method. After I pass the variable size I want to use the code in my other file that uses the variable size to print it out. Basically in this method mySquare , myLine, myCube, and char2D I just want to use a method to pass the variables "size" to them. Please note that size is a different variable that is broken in my switch statement at the top.

Comment: Are the methods in your other class static or instance methods?

Comment: @khelwood They're instance methods

Comment: Then you need to make an instance of your other class and then call the methods using that instance. Since I can't see your other code, I can't tell you exactly how to do that.

Comment: @khelwood I added the other code in the original question and it is beneath the bold. The tricky thing though is that it extends from another class called char2D that I still haven't completed yet though. I thought I would try the other coding then figure it out later.

Comment: If your code is relying on other code that is all half-written, it is not going to compile. Also, please stop naming your classes the same things as your methods. It makes code much harder to follows. Classes in Java should start with a capital letter.

Comment: @khelwood Ah okay. Thanks. I'll try finishing all my other code and if I can't figure it out I'll open a discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Lets start with the first problem, you commented that you are trying to use  inheritance. There is couple things you have to remember the "Parent class", is usually where you build a set type of methods that I will call lower in the inheritance.

Here is a small code snip of how I would build an inheritance Parent Class.

```
public abstract class Animal 
{
//data member
private String animalType;

//getter
public String getAnimalType() {
    return animalType;
}

//1-arg constructor
Animal(String animalType)
{
    this.animalType = animalType;
}

public abstract String reproduce();

}
```

And here is one Subclass that is direct with Animal

```
public class Mammle extends Animal
{
    private String mammalType;

//1-arg constructor
Mammle(String mammalType)
{
    //must do an explict call to supper
    super("mammal");
    this.mammalType = mammalType;
}


public String getMammalType()
{
    return mammalType;
}

public String reproduce()
{
    return("This " + this.getMammalType() + " gives live birth.");
}
}//end of class


   //this is a subclass of mammle
   public class Platypus extends Mammle implements layeggs 
  {

//data member
public String platypusName;

//1-arg
public Platypus(String platypusName)
{
    super("platypus");
    this.platypusName = platypusName;
}


public String getPlatypusName() {
    return platypusName;
}

//implement the abstract method from interface
public String layAnEgg()
{
    return("this " + this.getMammalType() + " Lays eggs to reproduce");
}
}//end of class
```

This is how you would set up a proper inheritance then this is how I would make the driver class look like

```
public class pregotesr {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    //create a platypus pbject
    Platypus platOne = new Platypus("Penelope");


    System.out.println("The platOne object is a " + platOne.getAnimalType());
    System.out.println("The platOne object is a " + platOne.getMammalType());
    System.out.println("Platypus reproduction method: " + platOne.reproduce()); 
}
}
```

I usually always create an Object in the driver class for the specific class I want to call and insert what ever method I want to use. For example you want to set the **size** of **Square**

```
 square.setSize();
```

Comment: Ahhh thank you. This helps a lot comparedto my professors coding that has no comments